# Oracle character set data is not being displayed in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding, oracle9i

I have stored data in the Oracle database 9i in the WE8MSWIN1252 characterset in URDU and now I want to display this data on browser with asp.net, but the data is not being displayed accurately it is displaying in chinese-like language.

Can anyone tell me how can translate this data into actual URDU form?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot properly encode Urdu data in `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2` data types if the database character set is Windows-1252.  You can only encode the characters that are part of the [Windows-1252 character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which is a Western European character set.  You would need to either use `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR2` data types (assuming your national character set supports Urdu) or change the database character set of the database.  There is a chapter in the Globalization Support Guide that discusses [how to change the character set of an existing database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch10.htm#1656).

Comment: Yes Sir I Have My Data stored in nvarchar2 data type but i don't know to dispaly it on web in asp.net Please tell me To Do this

Comment: @user1103342 - What is the national character set of your database?